# Why are there missing commands on some manpages?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, man

Early on in my Linux journey, I found some manpages to be lacking. One example is that on Fedora 37, I forgot the command to display the total filesize of all files in a directory. I knew it involved the `du` program, but I did not know the way to display the result in MB and GB. When I enter the command `man du`, there is absolutely no mention of the `-h` option, but when I performed a web search, I learned that the `-h` option would do exactly what I was looking for, and it did.

Why do some manpages like this not list all commands for the program? Is this a common occurrence?

Comment: Did you open the POSIX du manage instead of the GNU one?

Comment: @muru does Fedora have POSIX man pages available with `man du`?

Comment: Fedora has the only `du` utility from the coreutils package.

Comment: @roaima https://fedora.pkgs.org/36/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-aarch64/man-pages-posix-2017a-1.fc36.noarch.rpm.html lists a `/usr/share/man/man1p/du.1p.gz` (I know it's an old release but I'd guess newer releases will be similar -  though I'm not all that familiar with Fedora's package index)

Answer (score 1):

Fedora absolutely has this in its `du` man page (belongs to the `coreutils-common-9.1-8.fc37.x86_64.rpm` package):

```
       -H     equivalent to --dereference-args (-D)

       -h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

> Why do some manpages like this not list all commands for the program? Is this a common occurrence?

I don't think what you're describing pertains to the real world. In my experience Fedora has lacked man pages for some obscure rarely used utilities but again it's a *very* rare occurrence for upstream packages which lack man pages themselves.